# Is This How Association Work In C++?

Tags: c++, associations

```
class Staff{

public:
void createTeacher(TeacherRecord tr);

  tr.addTeacher();

}

class TeacherRecord{

public:
void addTeacher();
}
```

The logic to add the teacher will be in the TeacherRecord addTeacher() method.
In this scenario a Staff uses the TeacherRecord object to add a new Teacher in to the list. Can this be called as Assocation Relationship?

Comment: It is unclear what `addTeacher` and `createTeacher` do. Perhaps show an example of usage.

Comment: What is a 'Teacher' and what list is it added to?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Association relationship as defined by UML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically no.According to the definition of association, the `class Staff` and the `class Teacher` should use each other.So the code should have been something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class TeacherRecord{

 public:
  void addTeacher(Staff school_staff);
};

class Staff{

 public:
  void createTeacher(TeacherRecord tr){
   tr.addTeacher(this);
  }

};
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

A few references which have helped me in understanding the concept are:

1. [This stack overflow question.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255973/c-association-aggregation-and-composition)
2. [This code project article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330447/Understanding-Association-Aggregation-and-Composit)

Sorry for my long code.Hope this helps.